# How to get only text inside div tag and src content of img tag in by using regular expression javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string generated with this format :

```
'fdffddf<div><br> <div><img style="max-width: 7rem;" src="folder/myimg.jpg"><div> <br></div></div><div><div> <br></div></div></div>'.
```

I want to create a regular expression .
I want a regular expression that just fetches me the content without the div tag and the source of the image in an array.

Example in my case:
`[ 'fdffddf', 'folder/myimg.jpg' ]`

I tried this method :

```
let str = 'fdffddf<div><br> <div><img style="max-width: 7rem;" src="folder/myimg.jpg"><div> <br></div></div><div><div> <br></div></div></div>'
console.log('only content without div tag and src image only without img tag : ',str.match(/<img [^>]*src="[^"]*"[^>]*>/gm)[0])
```

It doesn't work. I get only the img tag.

How can I do it please ?

Comment: Experts always advice NOT to parse html with regex, you should tools/languages which understand html well IMHO.

Comment: [Why not to use a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not) - The safe way would be to use `DOMParser()` to parse the markup into actual `HTMLElements` and then extract the relevant parts.

Comment: Hi @Andreas,would it be possible to do it only in javascript with a regular expression or even two regular expressions to arrive at the final result

Comment: Maybe. Depends on the content of `str`. But I wouldn't do it that way - unless the content of `str` is super-simple and not provided by the user or any external resource. Just use a `DOMParser()`...

Comment: hi @Andreas , More simply, if possible, can you give me an example in my case where I just retrieve the content inside the div tag or outside the div tag with a regular expression in javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please keep in mind that using regex to parse HTML is error prone. If you want to play safe it is better to use an HTML parser.

Here is a regex approach to extract the img src and to strip the remaining text of HTML:

```js
const str = 'fdffddf<div><br> <div><img style="max-width: 7rem;" src="folder/myimg.jpg"><div> <br></div></div><div><div> <br></div></div></div>';
let arr = str
  .replace(/<img\b.*?src="([^"]*).*?>/, '$1') // extract img src
  .split(/<\/?[a-z]\w*\b[^>]*>/i)  // split on HTML tags
  .filter(s => s.trim()); // filter out empty items and spaces only items
console.log(arr);
```

Output:

```
[
  "fdffddf",
  "folder/myimg.jpg"
]
```

Explanation of `.replace()` regex:

- `<img` -- start of tag with tag name
- `\b` -- word boundary
- `.*?` -- non-greedy scan until:
- `src="` -- literal `src="` text
- `([^"]*)` -- capture group with everything not a double quote
- `.*?` -- non-greedy scan until:
- `>` -- end of tag

Explanation of `.split()` regex:

- `<` -- start of tag
- `\/?` -- optional slash (end tag)
- `[a-z]\w*` -- tag name: single alpha char followed by 1+ word chars
- `\b` -- word boundary after tag name
- `[^>]*` -- scan over anything not end of tag
- `>` -- end of tag

Answer (score -1):

You can do it with the following regex:

```
/^(?<!<)(\b[^<>]+\b)(?!>).*(?<=")(\b.+\b)(?=")/
```

This regex uses two capturing groups, one for the string at the beginning and one for the image source.

Try the following code:

```
const string = 'fdffddf<div><br> <div><img style="max-width: 7rem;" src="folder/myimg.jpg"><div> <br></div></div><div><div> <br></div></div></div>';
const regex = /^(?<!<)(\b[^<>]+\b)(?!>).*(?<=")(\b.+\b)(?=")/;
const match = string.match(regex);
console.log(`text: ${match[1]} - source: ${match[2]}`);
```